# How to sketch the graph of $y = \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

This diagram shows the graphs of the functions $y = f(x)$ and $y = g(x)$.

> [image]

The question is -

> Sketch the graph of $y = \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$.
>   Indicate clearly where
>   the y-intercept, the x-intercepts, and any asymptotes occur.

I have been working on this problem for almost an hour and can't figure out how to sketch the graph. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you already found the three things you were asked to highlight?

Comment: @Gae.S. No, I haven't.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_sketching

Comment: Hint What happens when $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=g(x)$

Comment: Start by building a x | f | g | g/f  table for x = 0, 1, 3, etc. The f,g values can be taken from the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am correct, the question is asking you to sketch the graph in the same paper.

to sketch $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ , see the corresponding values, i.e output

At x = 0, we can see that $f(x) = -4$ and $g(x) = -2$ $\implies$ $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 2 $

Now, Mark the point (0,2) on the graph sheet.
Similarly for the points at $ x = 8 $ and at the points where they have same output which is at $ f(x) = g(x) = -2 $ and at $f(x) = g(x) = -1 $

Join all the points and you have the graph of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

y-intercept is where the graph cuts the y-axis which is at x=0 and hence y-intercept = 2

The graph cuts x-axis when $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0 \implies f(x) = 0 $ so, it will be in between x = 3 and x = 4

the graph has an asymptote when $g(x) = 0$ which is somewhere in between x = 6 and x = 7

Hope this helps.